# I am in the middle

Tags: word-choice

How do I answer this question below correctly? I have two brothers. My elder brother is 37 and my younger brother is 25 and I am in the middle.
Is "I am in the middle" correct? Do native speakers use "a middle child"?

"How many siblings do you have? What's your birth order?"

"The Complete Book of Questions" by Garry Poole.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exactly, it is the correct way to answer that question but be careful of the context and situation when using this sentence. Like you can first answer the first part of the question being asked and then say "I'm the middle child".

Answer (score 2):

This may be a regional thing but we would say say the order of children.

> I am the second oldest of three (kids).

In direct relation to your question above I would answer like this.

> *My elder brother is 37, my younger brother 25 and I'm in between.*

in larger families the reference tends to be eldest or youngest.

> I'm the second eldest and my sister is the youngest

Comment: "I am the second oldest" because I am 35 and my brother is 37. Right? But If I had 3 brothers and two  sisters.  The oldest was 37 the second oldest was 35 the third oldest was 34 and one of my sisters   was 19, my second youngest sister was 22 and I was 21.  Would it be correct to say I am the second youngest?

Comment: if you are 21, you are the second youngest, the 19 year old would be the youngest and just to make it interesting your 22 year old sister would be the oldest sister but the fourth child or sibling.

Comment: If my sister is 25 and  she is the youngest, my brother is 35 I am 37 and my elder brother is 40, am the second oldest?

Comment: yes you are the second oldest and also the oldest daughter.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question again! :)

Comment: Is "eldest" also used in "the second eldest" or should it be "oldest" only?